# Get keyboard in plug-in of eclipse jdt

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I want get keyboard in plug-in of eclipse jdt. 
Example:

When I pressed "aaa" then my plug-in must get "aaa". ok?

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Google for EventListener tutorials or examples like a drawing canvas.
You can listem for key strokes or mouse movement/clicks.